# Cryptic error integrating sentry.io with gitlab.com

Tags: gitlab, sentry

I tried integrating Sentry.io with gitlab.com by following [their instructions](https://docs.sentry.io/product/integrations/source-code-mgmt/gitlab/). And hit the following cryptic error message:

```
Whoops! Looks like something went wrong! Give that another try.

An error occurred while validating your request.
```

Not the most helpful message! Anyone seen this before? How did you resolve it?

[image]

Comment: At what step does this happen? Did you follow the [troubleshooting section](https://docs.sentry.io/product/integrations/source-code-mgmt/gitlab/#troubleshooting)?

Comment: Yes, looked at that as well. None of them seem to apply.